# Num rows always 0 with prepared statment

Tags: php, mysqli

I try to use `num_rows` with prepared statment but always the result is `num_rows 0`

**DB:**

```
============
name | code
============
test | 1
```

**Php:**

```
function Add(){
    $global $name;
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $name);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->get_result();

    if ( $stmt->num_rows > 0 ) {
        echo "Exist name";
        $stmt->close();
        $mysqli->close();
    }else {
    //OTHER CODE
    }
}
```

When I try to `print num_rows` it returns 0 but the result should be 1.

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use `mysqli_stmt::get_result()` to convert the result-set to a MySQLi result object, the results from the statement is exhausted - and you can now check the `num_rows` property of the resulting object instead.

```
function Add(){
    global $name;
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $name);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result(); // Assign the result to a variable

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) { // Check the number of rows in the MySQLi result object
        echo "Exist name";
        $stmt->close();
        $mysqli->close();
    } else {
        //OTHER CODE
    }
}
```

Alternatively, drop the `get_result()` method if you don't intend to use the result (if you just want to check for the number of rows).

```
function Add(){
    global $name;
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $name);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        echo "Exist name";
        $stmt->close();
        $mysqli->close();
    } else {
        //OTHER CODE
    }
}
```

Yet another way is to check if the `$stmt->fetch()` returned a truthy value, which will indicate that at least 1 row exists (you need to remove the `get_result()` method for this as well).

This would be my preferred approach to see if there was any results returned.

```
if ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "Exist name";
}
```

Comment: your second code won't work

Comment: Care to elaborate on that...?

Comment: I am sure you can find out yourself, it is qute a duplicate question on Stack Overflow

Comment: To explain what YCS meant. You need to either get or store the results. num_rows on the statement will be empty otherwise.

Comment: Also what's with the global $name?

Comment: Fair point about the `store_result()`, I completely forgot that. Which would've been nice to just say "*You forgot to store the result*" instead.. ;-) About the `global $name`, better ask OP, that's what he had, no idea why.